# Pantheon files will not auto mount cdrom or dvdrom media. How do I do this via command line?

Tags: pantheon-files, mount

When I remote into my machine using ssh, I am unable to access any optical media because pantheon files has not mounted the media. Is there a command line utility (preferably other than editing fstab) to mount cdrom media just like  pantheon files does when I click on it?

Answer (score 1):

I'ts pretty simple to do

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom && sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

This will first create the folder /mnt/cdrom (mkdir = make directory) and then mount the cdrom (/dev/cdrom) to that directory.

Comment: I know how to do it manually. I want it to be automatic just like pantheon-files does when I click on it. Also, when I insert a DVD for example, then click on it in Files, it gets mounted in my home directory in a folder which is named for the TITLE of the disc. I would love to be able to replicate this via terminal.

Comment: Im pretty sure the command I gave above is the same command Pantheon Files uses. If you want to mount it in /home/cdrom you can change the command to sudo mkdir /home/cdrom && sudo mount /dev/cdrom /home/cdrom. Also an note: Pantheon Files does NOT automaticly mount cd roms...

Comment: I think I may be able to achieve this by using `e2label` to get the cdrom or dvdrom label, then `mkdir`, then `mount` as you suggested. I am not able to test this remotely as there is not a disk in the drive right now.